What makes my PostScript file annotated?
I have created a little PostScript program which is now executed well using emacs and its PostScript debugger. When I try to convert it to pdf using ps2pdf -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -sPAPERSIZE=a4  -r1200 Example.ps /tmp/Example.pdf, I get the message saying
GPL Ghostscript 10.00.0: Page object was reserved for an Annotation destination, but no such page was drawn, annotation in output will be invalid.
What makes this PostScript program, which is using the PostScript Language Document Structuring Conventions, a wrong annotation ?

I'm using the latest standard debian distribution (bookworm). -dDELAYBIND has not changed the output message. The generated pdf file has only 1 page, but the input file has two.

Don't use -dDELAYBIND unless you know exactly why you are doing it. Similarly for -dNOSAFER. As K J says nobody can help without seeing the PostScript program, sorry but that's all I can say. I'd also suggest you don't use the ps2pdf shell script, it does nothing more than add confusion. Instead execute Ghostscript directly and use -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o out.pdf. I really wouldn't specify a resolution to pdfwrite, it isn't helpful unless it needs to render the content which, coming from PostScript, it won't.

I will try to send the postscript code to KenS for examination.

Thanks to KenS, I have found an error in my ps code. The last page had no corresponding showpage command. The result was this surprising error diagnostic because the interpreter was supposing that there is a not terminated annotation.
